# Castle Windsor: how to know that the container has been initialized or configured?

Tags: configuration, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor with a configuration from my App.config file.

In the code I use :

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
```

to get the container.

But for some configurations of my application I don't want to use CastleWindsor (for some migration issues...) and therefore, I don't want to add any Castle section in my App.config.

And the problem is that if there is no castle config, then

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
```

throws an exception "Could not find section 'castle' in the configuration file associated with this domain."

So basically in my code I want to do something like:

```
if (IsCastleWindsorInitialized()) {/* do something */ } else {  /* do something else */ }
```

where 'IsCastleWindsorInitialized()' returns true when the App.config contains a castle section.

In order to implement that function I can certainly use the ConfigurationManager but I'm  wondering if I can use Castle Windsor API to do that.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea... Could you elaborate on "some configurations of my application"? What configurations?

Comment: I agree that this is not a good idea. And sorry for not being clear...I have actually an assembly which is used in many applications and I want to use CastleWindsor in that assembly. This implies that I should change all the configuration files to include a 'Castle' section. Unfortunately, I do not have the time now... I would prefer leaving some of the application with a 'default behaviour, not configured with Castle Windsor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probe the app.config with a ConfigurationManager.GetSection("castle") (that is, if you use XML-only configuration)

Comment: With ConfigurationManager it is ok. As written in my question, I wanted to know if that could be achieved without it, using CastleWindsor API only.